# Visualizing a complex vector space of arrows?

Tags: vector-spaces, visualization

**Real vector space.** A real scalar $a \in \mathbb{R}$ acting on a 3-dimensional vector $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ can be visualized as the *shrinking or stretching* of $\vec{v}$ by a factor of $a$.

**Complex vector space.** Suppose now $z \in \mathbb{C}$.  Is there a common or intuitive way to visualize what $z$ does to $\vec{v}$ in the case of

$$
z \vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^3
$$

?

Comment: If $\vec v\in\mathbb R^3$, and $z\in\mathbb C$ how is $z\vec v \in\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Andrei: Perhaps that's the beginning of my confusion.  I thought that complex scalars could act on vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: They can, but the outcome is in $\mathbb C^3$, the equivalent of $\mathbb R^6$

Comment: Andrei: Why can't we let complex scalars act on elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$ in such a way that they are closed?  Where is the contradiction?

Comment: I thought that you are using $z\vec v=(zv_1,zv_2, zv_3)$. If $z=i$ and $\vec v=(1,1,1)$ then $z\vec v=(i,i,i)$ none of the elements of the output is real.

Comment: Any $\Bbb C$ vector space can be seen as an $\Bbb R$ vector space with *double dimension*.

Comment: If you let $\Bbb C$ act on $\Bbb R^n$, i.e., define a multiplication with the properties $z(v_1+v_2)=zv_1+zv_2$, $(z_1+z_2)v=z_1v+z_2v$, $z_1(z_2v)=(z_1z_2)v$, $1v=v$, then necessarily $n$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

This nice [notebook](https://github.com/stephencwelch/Imaginary-Numbers-Are-Real/blob/master/Image%20Mapping.ipynb) shows you how to map images using $f(z)=z^2$[image: projected image on the complex plane]

Comment: I don't think this addresses complex scalar multiplication as in the questions at all.